# image upload to server of php error come in response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Tags: java, php, android, http-post, httpclient

i was make two file one is mainActivity and second is MultipartEntity 
i post both file

MainActivity.java

```
                  package com.example.picupload;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button mTakePhoto;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private static final String TAG = "upload";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        mTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.take_photo:
            takePhoto();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void takePhoto() {
//      Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
//      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
//      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + this);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            setPic();
//          Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
//          if (bitmap != null) {
//              mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//              try {
//                  sendPhoto(bitmap);
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          }
        }
    }

    private void sendPhoto(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {
        new UploadTask().execute(bitmap);
    }

    private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            if (bitmaps[0] == null)
                return null;
            setProgress(0);

            Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.8.84:8003/savetofile.php"); // server

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                Log.i(TAG, "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (response != null)
                        Log.i(TAG, "response " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                } finally {

                }
            } finally {

            }

            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.uploaded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    File photoFile = null;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
     */
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/picupload";
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(TAG, "photo path = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postRotate(90);
        // Rotating Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);

        if (rotatedBMP != bitmap)
            bitmap.recycle();

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);

        try {
            sendPhoto(rotatedBMP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MultipartEntity.java

```
package com.example.picupload;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

public class MultipartEntity implements HttpEntity {

    private String boundary = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    boolean isSetLast = false;
    boolean isSetFirst = false;

    public MultipartEntity() {
        this.boundary = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
    }

    public void writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds(){
        if(!isSetFirst){
            try {
                out.write(("--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
            } catch (final IOException e) {

            }
        }
        isSetFirst = true;
    }

    public void writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds() {
        if(isSetLast){
            return ;
        }
        try {
            out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
        isSetLast = true;
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String value) {
        writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
        try {
            out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +key+"\"\r\n").getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write(value.getBytes());
            out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName, final InputStream fin){
        addPart(key, fileName, fin, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName, final InputStream fin, String type){
        writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
        try {
            type = "Content-Type: "+type+"\r\n";
            out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+ key+"\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n").getBytes());
            out.write(type.getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n".getBytes());

            final byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
            int l = 0;
            while ((l = fin.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                out.write(tmp, 0, l);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final File value) {
        try {
            addPart(key, value.getName(), new FileInputStream(value));
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds();
        return out.toByteArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public Header getContentType() {
        return new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChunked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRepeatable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStreaming() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        outstream.write(out.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public Header getContentEncoding() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void consumeContent() throws IOException,
    UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (isStreaming()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Streaming entity does not implement #consumeContent()");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
    UnsupportedOperationException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

saveimage.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {
    // Example:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], "upload/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
    echo 'successful';
}
?>
```

geting error in

> try {
>                         response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
>                     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }

please help me to solve..

Comment: It will be get direct exception and it will not be respond anything.

Comment: OK, Can you debug it and see the value of e in ClientProtocolException?

Comment: yes i done already debug. its null coming. after 2 or 3 minits exception catch and its null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working for me and please try to different network like wifi or mobile data

> // Making server call
>
> HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
>                 HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
>
> ```
>           int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
>           if (statusCode == 200) {
>               // Server response
>               responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
>           } else {
>               responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
>                       + statusCode;
>           }           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>           responseString = e.toString();          } catch (IOException e) {
>           responseString = e.toString();          }           return responseString;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use this method for sending image to server

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";


public static JSONObject sendJSONDataWithImage() {

    String Content = null;

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.8.84:8003/savetofile.php");

    File file = new File(yourFilePathwithfileName);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    int size = (int) file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    ByteArrayBody bab = null;
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(file));
        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buf.close();
        bab = new ByteArrayBody(bytes, yourFilePathwithfileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(otherParameter,chars));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    reqEntity.addPart("myFile", bab);

    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    // execute HTTP post request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        String sResponse;
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        json = s.toString();

        System.out.println("Response.............: " + json);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
         jObj = new JSONObject(json);
         Log.e("add emp with img Response", "> " + json.toString());
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
     }

    return jObj;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
package com.secondhandbooks.http;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.secondhandbooks.util.ConvertStreamIntoString;
import com.secondhandbooks.util.SaveImageIntoDrawable;

public abstract class BaseAsync_Post extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>
{

    Context context ;
    private HttpPost httppost;
    String url ;
    Dictionary<String, String> dictionary ;


    public BaseAsync_Post(String url , Dictionary<String, String> dictionary, Context context) {
        this.url = url ;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
        this.context = context ;

        Enumeration<String> enumeration = dictionary.keys() ;


        showLogs("constructor") ;

        while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            showLogs( enumeration.nextElement() ) ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    abstract protected void onPreExecute() ;
    @Override
    abstract protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) ;

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream is = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        try 
        {   
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(50);

            Enumeration<String> enumeration = dictionary.keys() ;

            while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() )
            {
                String key = enumeration.nextElement() ;

                if ( key.equals("file") )
                {
                    final File file = new File(SaveImageIntoDrawable.savedImagePath);

                    if ( file.isFile() )
                    {
                        showLogs("is file");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showLogs("no-file");
                    }

                    FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);
                    entity.addPart(key, fb);                        
                }
                else
                {
                    entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(dictionary.get(key)));
                }
            }

            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity1);

            is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showLogs("ClientProtocolException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showLogs("IOException");
        }

        return is;
    }

    public String getString(JSONObject json, String TAG) {
        String returnParseData = "";

        try {
            Object aObj = json.get(TAG);
            if (aObj instanceof Boolean) {
                returnParseData = Boolean.toString(json.getBoolean(TAG));
            } else if (aObj instanceof Integer) {
                returnParseData = Integer.toString(json.getInt(TAG));
            } else if (aObj instanceof String) {
                returnParseData = json.getString(TAG);
            } else {
                returnParseData = json.getString(TAG);
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            returnParseData = "";
        }

        return returnParseData;
    }

    public String getIntintoString(JSONObject json, String TAG) {
        int returnParseData = -1;

        try {
            returnParseData = json.getInt(TAG) ;
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            returnParseData = -1;
        }

        return Integer.toString(returnParseData) ;
    }

    public void showLogs ( String msg )
    {
        Log.e("HTTP-POST", msg) ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code in your android, it works for me,

```
    String url = "";// URL where image has to be uploaded
    String fileName = ""; //path of file to be uploaded
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    FileBody fileContent = new FiSystem.out.println("hello");
    StringBody comment = new StringBody("Filename: " + fileName);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Hope this helps you with your problem...!!!!!

Comment: not working.. just error when  HttpResponse response is call... i debug that. its geting null

Comment: we have this below from server side
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {
    // Example:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], "upload/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
    echo 'successful';
}
?>

Comment: I have no knowledge of PHP code, Pls check with some php code this upload working or not